# Get-ADPrincipalGroupMembership forward slash error

Tags: powershell

I have this line of code that generally works until one of the user's group names has a / forward slash in it. I then get a non-terminating error for that user and the user doesn't get processed correctly. I've heard about escaping characters, but I don't know where you'd do that in this line of code?

```
Get-ADPrincipalGroupMembership -Identity $User.SamAccountName | Select Name | Where-Object {$_.Name -like 'GroupName*'} | ForEach-Object { $User_MemberOf += @($_.Name) }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry, there isn't any way to escape it. It is a bug within Powershell.

See this [bug report page](https://connect.microsoft.com/PowerShell/Feedback/Details/1190397) for more info.

Your options:

- *Remove any forward slashes (`/`) within AD*, as [this user](https://serverfault.com/q/749559) did. However, this probably isn't an option for you.
- *Use `Get-ADObject` instead*. This also isn't very pretty, but as [reported here](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsserver/en-US/23fc0c30-f7c8-4843-be99-fea9fe8ca036/error-on-getadprincipalgroupmembership-for-groupnames-with-?forum=winserverDS), it may work for you.

Comment: Bummer. Ok, will do... Thx